# How to install pgTAP on Windows?

Tags: unit-testing, winapi, installation, mingw, pgtap

I have been trying to install **pgTAP** on **Windows** for hours and could not figure it out.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I installed **strawberry perl** and GnuWin32 in order to run `Makefile`.

Here are some of the errors I got:

```
make
'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command
'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command
akefile:42: C:/strawberry/c/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
rocess_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, which perl, ...) failed.
makefile:56: To use pg_prove, TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::pgTAP Perl module
makefile:57: must be installed from CPAN. To do so, simply run:
makefile:58: cpan TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::pgTAP
```

I also installed **Cygwin64** to run `Makefile`.

```
$ make
makefile:42: C:/Program: No such file or directory
makefile:42: Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file o                                  r directory
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, /usr/bin/perl -le "eval { require TAP::Parser                                  ::SourceHandler::pgTAP }; print 1 unless $@", ...) failed.
makefile:56: To use pg_prove, TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::pgTAP Perl module
makefile:57: must be installed from CPAN. To do so, simply run:
makefile:58: cpan TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::pgTAP
make: *** ▒^▒[▒Q▒b▒g `Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk' ▒▒ ma                                      ke ▒▒▒郋▒[▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒܂▒▒▒.  ▒▒▒~.
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Looks like file names with spaces are not properly handled in [the `Makefile`](https://github.com/theory/pgtap/blob/master/Makefile). Anyone know how to get `include $(PGXS)` to properly quote the value in `$PGXS`?

Answer (score 4):

Since you need to use pgTAP with Postgres 9.2, you can just make a few modifications of the source file and copy it directly. See [this wiki page](http://www.oscon.com/oscon2010/public/wiki/TestDrivenDatabaseDevelopment#windows) for details. To summarize, once you have [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) or [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) installed, run these commands:

```
copy sql/pgtap.sql.in sql/pgtap.sql
perl.exe -pi.bak -e "s/TAPSCHEMA/tap/g" sql/pgtap.sql
perl.exe -pi.bak -e "s/__OS__/win32/g" sql/pgtap.sql
perl.exe -pi.bak -e "s/__VERSION__/0.24/g" sql/pgtap.sql
perl.exe -pi.bak -e "s/^-- ## //g" sql/pgtap.sql
copy sql/pgtap.sql "%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\9.2\share"
```

As for `pg_prove`, on Strawberry Perl, you can install [from CPAN](https://metacpan.org/release/TAP-Parser-SourceHandler-pgTAP), like so:

```
cpan TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::pgTAP
```

On ActivePerl, you can install [the PPM](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/TAP-Parser-SourceHandler-pgTAP/):

```
ppm install TAP-Parser-SourceHandler-pgTAP
```

Comment: Any recent update for this?
I have a similar problem but these patterns have changed.
In particular, I would like to change the default schema (other than public...)